# Bogus Git error message... can't fix or work around it

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

Something has happened to my local copy of a Git repo. When I try to synch it to the server (`git pull`) I get the following message.

```
Updating 060b8f7..af17d97
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        docs/user-guide/images/Databricks/initscript.png
        docs/user-guide/images/Databricks/initscript_ucx.png
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Now, I have never changed those two files. In fact before I got the error I had never visited a directory farther down that path than `user-guide`. Furthermore this is happening in branch `main`, and I would never change *anything* there; I never even check it out except to go a `git pull` or create a new working branch.

I tried stashing the changes as the error suggests. `git stash` gave me this:

```
Saved working directory and index state WIP on main: 060b8f7 Merge branch 'js-23c06-Incorrect-brackets-in-Qualification-tool-docs' into 'main'
Encountered 2 files that should have been pointers, but weren't:
        docs/user-guide/images/Databricks/initscript.png
        docs/user-guide/images/Databricks/initscript_ucx.png
```

Then I tried to pull, and I got the same "local changes would be overwritten" error. I also tried a hard reset and `git restore <filename>`. None of that affected the error.

I consulted the engineers I'm working with, and we agreed that I should save my changed files, delete and re-clone the repo, and reapply my changes. But to save my changed files I have to check out the branches they're in, and when I try to do that, Git gives me the "local changes would be overwritten" error again.

So there seems to be no way to restore the repo to usability without abandoning whatever work I've done in any branch.

Can anyone help?

Comment: agree with the engineers. can you copy/paste to new files?

Comment: Is your team using LFS on this repo?

Comment: Are you on a case insensitive filesystem? Is there, perhaps, a file with the same name but different case in the repo? Perhaps Databricks vs databricks? What does `git status` say?

Comment: can you run `git check-attr --all -- path/to/png` ?

Comment: btw: `git checkout --force <branch>` should take you to the other branch. Obviously: use with care, in other situations you could forcefully overwrite your uncommitted work.

Comment: @300baud, I'm unsure what your question means. Can I copy/paste what to new files?

Comment: @Jim Redmond, I suspect that the repo uses LFS, and that it is causing the problem. I didn't say so before because I didn't want to bias first responses. I asked my engineering contact about LFS, but his answer was vague; I don't think he knows much more about it than I do, which is almost nothing! I did run `git lfs pull`, but it made no difference.

Comment: @Schwern, I am using a case insensitive file system (Windows 11), but I checked the pathname and found no components that match case-insensitive duplicate objects. `git status` says nothing unusual: I'm on branch main, it's behind origin by 48 commits, use git pull to update, and it lists the two problem files as "modified" and "not staged for commit."

Comment: @LeGEC, I tried the command you suggested. Omitting the pathname prefix on each line, it says `diff: lfs ^n merge: lfs ^n test: unset ^n filter: lfs`. And *thank you* for the `git checkout --force` suggestion. I tried it, and it works; that won't fix the problem, but it will enable me to save any work I've done before I blow the repo away.

Comment: have you tried adding back the problematic files ? `git add that/png/file`

Comment: @LeGEC: I haven't tried adding back the files because GitLab says *something* is wrong with them; I just don't know what! If I add them back I'll satisfy the "changed files" issue, but may propagate the something-wrong from my local repo to the remote. That's assuming I could push a change at all. I suspect I couldn't, for the same reason that stash doesn't work... whatever that is! Anyway I've saved my work in other branches and I'm about to delete the local repo and re-clone it. I'd still like to understand what was wrong but I won't have the misbehaving repo to experiment with any more.